# Which capabilities are needed for statx to stop giving EPERM

Tags: linux, docker, linux-capabilities

I have a Qt project that uses a plugin interface which compiles fine on my system. However, when the same project is compiled inside docker it stopped working with Qt 5.10.1, giving the message`Error: Undefined interface`. After some `strace`ing the `moc` run, it turned out that a header file that defines the interface is not found because the `statx` call on the include's filepath always returns `EPERM`. The documentation does not even mention how this error can be generated.

`docker run --privileged` fixes this problem but I would like to avoid excessive permissions so I wanted to set only the necessary ones.

So far I tried to add all of these capabilities (even at the same time) without success:

- CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE
- CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH
- CAP_FOWNER
- CAP_SETFCAP

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

A [pull request](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36417) for this is pending.

Comment: Inside the same container, with the same configuration, can you access the same file through other means? That is, have you confirmed that the issue is specific to `statx`?

Comment: If it *is* specific to `statx` -- what is your output from `docker info | grep 'Security Options'`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can `cat` the file contents from inside the container without problems. The output from `docker info` is `Security Options: seccomp Profile: default`.

Comment: I'm guessing that Docker is using a seccomp profile that doesn't permit `statx`, but that's inconsistent with a blank "Security Options" list... unless it's been reformatted into multiple lines.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, it was reformatted into multiple lines. I folded it into one for the edited comment.

Comment: A wild ride from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277225 came here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Before 2018-03-06

`statx` isn't included in the [default `seccomp` whitelist](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/00c1c604d08bbceb73a680d37d7428e6a4e986af/profiles/seccomp/default.json) used by Docker as of present date.

You can use `--security-opt seccomp=/path/to/seccomp/profile.json` to specify a different profile (presumably, one with this syscall added).

---

#### After 2018-03-06

[`moby/moby#36417`](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36417) was [merged to master](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/f0694e968fe600efdf24ab0d3a1b0e887267aea2) as of March 6th, 2018.

It should be included in nightly builds going forward, and eventually in the Docker 18.04 release.

Comment: Is it possible to just add a syscall to the current profile or do I need to always mirror the default profile and add my own to make it work?

Comment: I'm not aware of a mechanism to add a syscall. Wouldn't be hard to write a `jq` expression to script adding a new entry to the list, though.

Comment: A pull-request to whitelist statx was opened here: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36417