# Make can't run mkdir as root in Alpine Linux container

Tags: docker, makefile, alpine-linux, musl

So, I'm trying to build musl-libc inside an Alpine Linux Docker container. The configure script succeeds, but make stops immediately because it can't run mkdir:

```
mkdir -p lib
make: mkdir: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:96: lib] Error 127
```

Using strace, I can see that it's getting EPERM when it checks access on the various mkdir symlinks, so it never actually runs the command itself:

```
faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/sbin/mkdir", X_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/bin/mkdir", X_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/sbin/mkdir", X_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/mkdir", X_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/sbin/mkdir", X_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
faccessat2(AT_FDCWD, "/bin/mkdir", X_OK, AT_EACCESS) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I have no idea why this is. I'm running make as root, and `/bin/busybox` has the executable bit set for all users anyway. I can create the directory just fine from the command line. What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

EDIT:
As requested, here's the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM alpine

ENV UTILS='vim tmux gdb strace git mandoc'
ENV DEPS='gcc make'

RUN apk update && apk add $DEPS $UTILS
ADD musl-src /musl-libc
ENV NPROC=6
RUN cd musl-libc && ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-debug && \
    make -j$NPROC
RUN cd musl-libc && make install
```

Requires the musl source in `./musl-src`.

Comment: Nah, looks like +x is set on / (and /bin). I added the Dockerfile above.

Comment: BTW, it's not just `mkdir`. Edit `musl-src/Makefile` to call any other command (`ls`, `cat`, etc) and it'll fail the same way.

Comment: Heh, think I've found it. Look at https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/19.03/profiles/seccomp/default.json -- `faccessat` is in the list of permitted syscalls, but not `faccessat2`.

Comment: This is https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41381

Comment: Nice! Updating to Docker 19.06+ (latest/beta channel on Ubuntu) fixed it for me. If you put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I remembered having seen something very much like this question before, and looking at it, the prior instance was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995826/which-capabilities-are-needed-for-statx-to-stop-giving-eperm. I'd argue that this is better closed as duplicate than answered; no reason to have more than one instance.

Comment: I'd strongly argue against closing this as duplicate, whilst https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995826 explains the underlying cause it's way too low-level and I'd never have found it in a search.   On the other hand, this one precisely matched the issue I was having and was one of the top search results.

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround: use bmake instead of make**

I hit this exact same problem in a containerised build on Alpine where `make` was GNU make 4.3.   The build would work fine on local Docker but fail on the ADO pipeline agents.   Alternatively the same sequence of commands that make was attempting, issued directly from `RUN`, also worked fine.

The pipeline agents are based on RHEL7 with the Docker version that RH choose to package.  I can't upgrade Docker on them, nor start it using special options and a different security profile.   It's managed by a different team and right out of my control.

With reference to comments above and the other question [Which capabilities are needed for statx to stop giving EPERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995826) it seems reasonable to guess that an alternate implementation of `make` might use the older `stat` rather than `statx` call which this old version of Docker has trouble with.

Indeed, NetBSD's `bmake` gives me a solution for now.

```
RUN apk add --upgrade gcc libc-dev bmake

RUN bmake dist
```