# Why can't I install libpaper1 with remote Docker 17.09?

Tags: docker, circleci

Why can I only install libpaper1 on CircleCI after upgrading to "remote Docker" version 20.10.7?

If you look at [the two most recent commits](https://github.com/ysangkok/broken-slim/commits/master), the second-to-last [fails to build](https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/ysangkok/broken-slim/11/workflows/aa1080b3-98f8-4ab6-97ec-d988af9ee06d/jobs/11). But the final one builds, and the only difference is that the Docker version has been upgraded.

The error on the second-to-last commit is:

```
Creating config file /etc/papersize with new version
stat: cannot statx '/etc/papersize.dpkg-inst': Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package libpaper1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpaper1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Why is [version 17.0.9 the default](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/#docker-version) if it is less capable than version 20.10.7?

Comment: Note that it may just be *changing* the engine version that invalidates a cache and makes the build succeed. Would need to understand how Docker versions interact with cache validation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `statx` not from `libepaper1`.
`statx` wasn't included in the default seccomp whitelist used by Docker before version 18.04.0, as we can see in the Docker Engine 18.04 release notes [page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/18.04/).

> Whitelist statx syscall. moby/moby#36417

**Thats why upgrading docker is the solution**.

Sources:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36417
- [Which capabilities are needed for statx to stop giving EPERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995826/which-capabilities-are-needed-for-statx-to-stop-giving-eperm)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672183/cannot-install-ghostscript-libgs9-and-libpaper1-on-debian-bullseye